# Express and MySQL server response not sending all of the required data

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, asynchronous, promise

I am trying to query a database for a project that I am working on that is used to teach and train users. I have two promises, one that queries the database for questions (and their question_ids) based on the type of user (e.g doctor), and then the next query takes the questions_ids, and selects the corresponding answers and answer_ids to the questions. The code is shown below:

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var path = require('path');
var async = require('async')

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "123456",
    database: "myDB"
})

app.set('port', 3001);

var questions = [];
var question_ids = [];
var answers = [];
var answer_ids = []

app.get('/training/:user_type', function (req, res) {
    var user_type = req.params.user_type // gets the value for the named parameter user_id from the url
    var sql_command_1 = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE type = ?"
    var sql_command_2 = "SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id = ?"

    function getQuestions() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            connection.query(sql_command_1, user_type, function (error, results) {
                for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    questions.push(results[i].question_text);
                    question_ids.push(results[i].question_id);
                }
                resolve({questions: questions, question_ids: question_ids});
            })
        })
    }

    function getAnswers(question_ids) {
        console.log(question_ids)
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            for (i = 0; i < question_ids.length; i++) {
                connection.query(sql_command_2, question_ids[i], function (error, results) {
                    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        answers.push(results[i].answer_text);
                        answer_ids.push(results[i].answer_id);
                    }
                    console.log(answers);
                    console.log(answer_ids);
                    resolve({answers: answers, answer_ids: answer_ids});
                });
            }
        });
    }


    getQuestions().then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        return getAnswers(result.question_ids);
    }).then((result) => {
        res.json({"Type": user_type, "Questions": questions, "Answers": answers});
    });
});

app.listen(app.get('port'));
```

My expected response is doctor for the user_type, two different questions for "Questions" and eight answers in "Answers" (four answers for each different question). However, I am only getting the four answers for the first question, not the four for the second. I've looked over the code and looked into asynchronous execution but can't seem to find my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

I will explain you what is wrong with your code, but first I want to propose you another approach to structure your application - **obtain all the data in a single query**

```
SELECT * FROM questions q 
LEFT JOIN answers a ON q.question_id = a.question_id
WHERE q.type = ?
```

this **SQL** will give you 8 records as a response looking something like:

```
question_id |  type  |  question  | answer_id | answer | .... all columns
1             doctor    question?       3        a       .......
1             doctor    question?       4        b       .......
1             doctor    question?       5        c       .......
1             doctor    question?       6        d       .......
2             doctor    question2?      11       ff      .......
2             doctor    question2?      12       gg      .......
2             doctor    question2?      13       hh      .......
2             doctor    question2?      14       mm      .......
```

then you simply can sort the data in `nodejs` - this way you will do only **one database call**.

With your approach you will do one request to the database to get all the questions and one more request per question to get it's answers - **3 requests total** in the scenario that you described. Imagine that you want to pull the answers for 50 questions - then you will do 50 requests ...

---

**Now ...** let's have look on your code.

First I see nested `for` loops that are using the same variable name for index - `i` **Never do that**

```
// This is a completely WRONG code
for (i = 0; i < question_ids.length; i++) {
    ...
    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Next

> However, I am only getting the four answers for the first question,
>   not the four for the second.

Yes, that's true because in `getAnswers()` method you are **resolving** your promise on the first database response. In such a scenario you can make an array of `Promise` and use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and the code will look like this:

```
function getAnswers(question_ids) {

    var promises = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < question_ids.length; i++) {
        promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            connection.query(sql_command_2, question_ids[i], function (error, results) {
                for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) { // change index with another letter here - j
                    answers.push(results[i].answer_text);
                    answer_ids.push(results[i].answer_id)
                }
                resolve();
            })
        });
        promises.push(promise);
    }

    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Let me know if something is not clear. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution, just added an if statement to make sure that the length of the questions array was the length required to be:

```
function getAnswers(question_ids){
  console.log(question_ids)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (i = 0; i < question_ids.length; i++){
      connection.query(sql_command_2, question_ids[i], function(error, results){
      for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
        answers.push(results[i].answer_text);
        answer_ids.push(results[i].answer_id)
      }
      if (answer_ids.length == (4 * question_ids.length)){
        console.log(answers)
        console.log(answer_ids)
        resolve({answers: answers, answer_ids: answer_ids})
    }
    })
   }
  }
)}
```

Comment: @codtex is right, their code is much more efficient :)

Comment: It is a very good sign for you as a programmer that you found a solution by yourself. I just wanted to point your mind to another, more efficient, approach and I'm glad that you understood how it works :) Good job!